# Win 7 XP Mode - tsClient connections slow

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

I am running Windows 7 XP Mode and want to access local C:\ drive on host, this can be done, but browsing the folder structure is not quick, and there are long wait periods.

Now I know this isn't a network latency issue - because the guest is running directly on the host, what else can I do to speed up \tsClient connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to install [this patch](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/10/15/download-kb972435-update-to-fix-slow-shared-folders-access-on-terminal-services-session-or-windows-xp-mode/) in the XP Virtual Machine.
More information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972435) in the Microsoft Knowledge Base.